# Executing async func inside another sync func freezes program

Tags: c++, asynchronous, lambda, concurrency, promise

My code looks something like this:

```
Future<ISomeClass*> Func1(
bool someCondition,
const InfoObj* info,
pVerify ...
) noexcept

{
    
      if (someCondition)
    
      {
        
           const_cast<OneAuthIdentity*> (info)->GetTicketAsync()
            
                       .Then([info, pVerify](TicketResult result) noexcept
        
                         {
            
                              pVerify->CheckExistence(
                
                              info,
                
                              [](const CustomObj& result) noexcept
            
                              {
                
                                      if (result.GetAccount())
                                      {
                                             cout<<"Get acct is true";
                                      }
                                      else
                                      {
                                             cout<<"Get acct is false";
                                      }
                              });
                        });
      }

    return promise.AsFuture();
}
```

Here GetTicketAsync() is an async function and returns a Future. Inside .then() of GetTicketAsync() i'm calling void CheckExistence() which calls an async func going ahead.

Issue:

Inside .then() of GetTicketAsync(), program freezes after CheckExistence is called and control never comes back to its lambda function.

It works fine if i move CheckExistence out of GetTicketAsync(). One thing i have observed is promise gets returned from Func1 even before CheckExistence gets called(). Does it have anything to do with the freezing of the program?

Comment: Why does it surprise you that the function returns before `CheckExistence` is called, when you're calling it asynchronously?

Comment: I suspect that `*info`, `*pVerify`, or both, have died by the time your `Then` callback executes. Also, using `const_cast` is very often a step on the path to problems.